Complexity of DLP vs ECDLP in MOV attack
In MOV attack we convert the ECDLP problem to a DLP problem in field of $F_{p^2}$ (assuming the embedding degree is 2). According to the answer here, the complexity of solving this DLP is
$e^{(1.92+o(1))(\log p)^{1/3}(\log\log p)^{2/3}}$ (possibly changing the $p$ to $p^2$ but ok).
The simplest algorithms for solving ECDLP such as Pollard's Rho are $O(\sqrt p)$ which is better than the DLP's complexity.
Why is MOV attack better?

Note that $O(\sqrt{p})$ is $\exp\big((\frac12+o(1))\log p\big)$, so exponential in $\log p$, whereas the complexity for the DLP is exponential in $(\log p)^{1/3}$ up to polynomial factors. Asymptotically, the latter is clearly better.
